# Query on results of a query

Tags: sql, subquery

I am new to sql and and have looked at many examples but have no idea how to make my query work. I ran the following query:

> select name, (select population/area) as density
>            from country

which listed all my country's and their population density (which was population divided by area).  However I want to run a query on the results that I got here to give me just one row that will return the country with the MAX density.  Is this possible, if so can you tell me how as everything I try and do just wont work?

Thanks for any help!

Terry

Comment: yes, make a query over this one as a subquery having it previously grouped by country.

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select top 1 name, (select population/area) as density from country
order by 2
```

Comment: Possible use without second SELECT statement